# wx python timer wont run continuously after dialog

Tags: python, timer, wxpython, messagedialog

I'm using Python and wxPython to interact between my user and an USB device. The USB device is somewhat slow in processing commands. Therefor, after sending the command, I'm showing a dialog notifying the user about the command and giving the device enough time to process the command. The code:

```
def ActionOnButtonClick( self, event ):
    # Send command to USB device;
    device.Send("command")

    # Notify user + allowing device to process command;
    dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent=None, message="Info", caption="Info", style=wx.OK)
    dlg.ShowModal()
    dlg.Destroy()

    # Start timer;
    self.RunTimer.Start(500)
```

When I run the code like this the "RunTimer" will run only once. After some testing I noticed that when I remove the messagedialog, the RunTimer will run continuously without any problems.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any thoughts/ideas?

Thank you in advance for your answer!

Best regards,

Peter

Comment: It's difficult to know what is going on because we don't know what the timer is doing and also whether you stop it or not.

Comment: @Rolf of Saxony, thank you for your response. The timer has a simple task: ask the device every interval for a certain status. The timer is never called to be stopped at this point. Again, the timer runs perfectly without the dialog in between. That is what makes it strange.

Comment: I'm surprised it fires at all. Calling `ShowModal` should block it from ever firing.

Comment: Until you click "OK"!

Answer (score 0):

@soep Can you run this test code. If in doubt start with the basics.

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title="Timer Dialog Test")
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, 1, label="Start Timer")
        self.button_1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton, id=1)
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.breaktimer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer, self.timer)

    def OnTimer(self, evt):
        print "timer"

    def OnButton(self,evt):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent=None, message="Starting Timer", caption="Timer Info", style=wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()
        self.timer.Start(1000)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```